# EF Core Navigational property with property other that key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Having problem creating navigational property using not key property but another foreign key.

```
public class Operation {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CodeId { get; set; }
    public Code Code { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CodeId { get; set; }
    public Code Code { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Code {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And inside `ModelBuider` I have

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>().HasKey(g => g.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>().HasMany(x => x.Task).WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CodeId).HasPrincipalKey(x => x.CodeId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasKey(g => g.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Code>().HasKey(g => g.Id);
```

Here I want to have Operation, which has navigation property `Tasks`. However this navigation property is not linked directly to `Task` class via `Id`, but it is linked via `CodeId`. So basically when fetching `Operation` I want to `Include()` all `Tasks`, which has the same `CodeId`.

So the querying part work all right, but when I try to update `Operation` entity, I get exception:

> Message: "The property 'CodeId' on entity type 'Operation' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal."

It makes sense that `CodeId` id not actual key or the property. But if I remove `HasPrincipalKey(x => x.CodeId)` from configuration, I cannot use `Include()` properly.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>().HasKey(g => g.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>().HasMany(x => x.Task).WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CodeId).HasPrincipalKey(x => x.CodeId);
```

So how do I use navigational property which are not directly linked via primary-foreign key?

Comment: Does this help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys

Comment: This is not gonna work. `Tasks` collection logically belongs to `Code` entity (as inverse navigation property of the one-to-many relationship by `Operation.Code`). And `Operation` tasks are represented by `Operation.Code.Tasks`

Comment: why you cannot use Include() properly if you remove the HasPrincipalKey() line? this is what is wrong with your current code, because CodeId is NOT part of a key.

Comment: @Stilgar haven't used `HasAlternateKeys()` but I'll give it a try. Just need to find example how to use wit navigation property.

Comment: @IvanStoev `Operation.Tasks` should be considered as read-only from `Operation` side. I just want `Operation` to list all `Tasks` that has the same `CodeId` as `Operation`

Comment: @DevilSuichiro In `ModelBuilder` I need to specify that `Operation` is linked to a `Task` not `Task.Id`, but rather  `Task.CodeId`. So that `Operation` with particular `CodeId` would include `Tasks` that has the same `CodeId` as `Operation`.

Comment: What you are describing is a *view* and not a *model*. The relational *model* is what I mentioned in the previous comment. all `Tasks` that has the same `CodeId` as `Operation` are `operation.Code.Tasks`. EF Core model navigation properties represent *direct* relationships only.

Comment: @IvanStoev I agree with you on that. However this is very specific scenario, because even though now `Code` is part of the same context and exists in the same database, but later on it will be fetched via other means from other database rather than using EF context as it is now. Obviously `public Code Code { get; set; }` will be no more, or it will be populated not using EF include option. Therefore I need to link `Operations` and `Tasks` keeping this in mind.